# localization in react.js suggestions and example

Tags: reactjs

We're on the decision on where to go on localization in react.js, surely there are ways to doing localization, but what would be your recommendation?

I tried yahoo's react-intl but to no avail:

```
var ReactIntl = require('react-intl') // we did npm install react-intl
// somewhere in the react component
render: function() {
    return (<div><ReactIntl.Number>{600}</ReactIntl.Number></div>);
}
```

gives the error: Cannot read property '_mockedReactClassConstructor' of undefined

spent few hours try to resolve this error, still can't resolve -> give up

I tried l20n by mozilla but not sure if it'll work with react.js

wondering what would you suggest for react.js localization, thanks!

Comment: yeah, the documentation is inadequate on react-intl and parent sites. Strugg

Comment: also I found the bug is from yahoo, release v1.1.0-rc-2 fixed the problem

Comment: did you ever resolve this? if so, can you post your solution? i'm encountering the same error while trying to use react-router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's been couple month from now. Perhaps there are more localisation modules out there. But if you wish to do something simple and bypass using so many modules (we only use essential modules lessen the load), here's the setup:

let's say we have a root page and login page (on our router setup, things are based on root page)

**root**

1. have a state called i18n (in getInitialState)
2. detect your language and init the i18n
3. set the object to i18n state
4. in render() use something like this

```js
render: function() {
    var route;
    if (this.state.configLoaded && this.state.i18n) {
        route = (
            <RouteHandler i18n={this.state.i18n} onLanguageChange={this._languageChangedHandler} />
        );
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Loading />
            {route}
        </div>
    );
}
```

and you pass i18n down through props. or if you wish, using mixins.

**login**

```
this.props.i18n.t('...')
```

Answer (score 3):

in response to my question. we decided not to use yahoo's react-intl but use i18next instead. Considering using something more stable and popular for our production is important.

what you can do is to initialize i18next at the root of your page, and pass that down through props. Do use a state to prevent page rendering before i18next is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

there is now react-i18next https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next works with i18next >=2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe use FormattedNumber from React-Intl for your purpose.
Things to consider, if you use i18next that only gives you translations , not Times/Dates/Currency etc, you'll need additional libraries like Moment.js. React-Intl gives you it all.
Watch out for IE<9 , you'll have to have the Intl.js polyfill or polyfill service (https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/docs/). I have found webpack to be problematic loading this polyfill.

Finally , with React-Router latest version see https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md

You'll probably find the section on RouteHandler worthwhile, use
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {someExtraProp: something })}
To pass your loacles/messages into views.

Hope that helps

Comment: Oh yes and passing stuff via context seems a whole lot easier than using props